# Wrap text in ConstraintLayout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-constraintlayout

I have to make a layout with following image using Constraint Layout (ver 1.1.2)
[image]

This is done, but there is an issue. When the value of any of the field is larger then the width available it get something like this:
[image]

I want to keep the alignments while warping the value text in consequent lines.
Here is the code for one row:

```
        <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/top_application_container"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constrainedWidth="true"
        app:layout_constraintWidth_default="wrap"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:background="@drawable/bg_white_header"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/top_client_container"
        >
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/top_application_label"
            style="?gsTrafficHistoryClientDetailLabel"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
            android:text="@string/top_application"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/top_application"
            style="?gsTrafficHistoryClientDetailValue"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
            android:text="YouTube.com YouTube.com YouTube.com"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/top_application_label"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            />
    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Now I have tried Relative Layout but I want to do it using Constraint Layout. Really appreciate any pointers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the concepts of chains in the constraint layouts using which I have achieved the layout you wanted as follows

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_left1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:padding="20dp"
        android:text="Most active client"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/tv_right1"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/tv_right1"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_right1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:padding="20dp"
        android:text="YouTube.com YouTube.com YouTube.com"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/tv_left1"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_left2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:padding="20dp"
        android:text="Most active client"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/tv_right2"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/tv_right2"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tv_left1"
        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_right2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:padding="20dp"
        android:text="YouTube.com YouTube.com YouTube.com"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/tv_left2"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tv_right1"
        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_left3"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:padding="20dp"
        android:text="Most active client"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/tv_right3"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/tv_right3"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tv_left2"
        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_right3"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:padding="20dp"
        android:text="YouTube.com YouTube.com YouTube.com"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/tv_left3"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tv_right2"
        />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

**Note:**Besides this you can use the concepts of the barrier which you can find [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/constraint/Barrier)

Answer (score 4):

Change Your TextView Width to match_constraint, the problem is wrap_content.

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/top_application_container"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@drawable/bg_white_header"
android:padding="5dp"
app:layout_constrainedWidth="true"
app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/top_client_container"
app:layout_constraintWidth_default="wrap">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/top_application_label"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    style="?gsTrafficHistoryClientDetailValue"
    android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:text="@string/top_application"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/top_application"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    style="?gsTrafficHistoryClientDetailValue"
    android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:text="YouTube.com YouTube.com YouTube.com"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/top_application_label"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 4):

Add `app:layout_constrainedWidth="true"` attribute to the `TextView` which is going to expand (`id/top_application`) to allow for `wrap_content` and enforce constraints at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

replace with below code

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    android:id="@+id/top_application_container"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_constrainedWidth="true"
    app:layout_constraintWidth_default="wrap"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:background="@drawable/bg_white_header"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/top_client_container"
    >
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/top_application_label"
        style="?gsTrafficHistoryClientDetailLabel"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:text="@string/top_application"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/top_application"
        style="?gsTrafficHistoryClientDetailValue"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:text="YouTube.com YouTube.com YouTube.com"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/top_application_label"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using constraintWidth_default & constraintWidth_percent like:

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="top_application"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintWidth_default="percent"
        app:layout_constraintWidth_percent=".5" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="YouTube.com YouTube.com YouTube.com YouTube.com YouTube.com YouTube.com YouTube.com YouTube.com YouTube.com"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintWidth_default="percent"
        app:layout_constraintWidth_percent=".5" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```